# how to identify duplicates adjacent to each other in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe as an example, how can I identify duplicates adjacent to each other and add the info to another column?

```
  G_NUM  PRIM   P_NUM   
0  15     True    135
1  9      False   147
2  9      True    264
3  9      False   537
4  2      False   154
5  10     False   222
6  10     False   370
7  10     False   188
8  14     True    215
```

I want the output to be shown as the following DF. The PRI column has a tuple that stores the sequence number, the total number of elements in a group, and the priority within the group.

For row 0 (G_NUM = 5), there is only one in the group, so it is 1/1 and the last element of tuple keeps the priority, which is 1 in this case. I want to set the PRI column to (1,1,1).

For rows 1 - 3 (G_Num=9), there are three of them, so they are 1/3, 2/3, and 3/3. For priority, I want those PRIM = True to have higher priority. If two adjacent members have the same PRIM status, the one that comes first has a higher priority.

How to make this happen? Thank you!

```
  G_NUM  PRIM   P_NUM   PRI
0  15     True    135   (1,1,1)
1  9      False   147   (1,3,2)
2  9      True    264   (2,3,1)
3  9      False   537   (3,3,3)
4  2      False   154   (1,1,1)
5  10     False   222   (1,3,1)
6  10     False   370   (1,3,2)
7  10     False   188   (1,3,3)
8  14     True    215   (1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a `df` like the first one above, work with `df.groupby` like this

```
In [1]: grouped = df.groupby('G_NUM').PRIM
In [2]: tuples = list(zip(grouped.cumcount() + 1, grouped.transform(len), grouped.transform(lambda x: np.argsort(~x.values, kind='mergesort')+1)))
In [3]: tuples 
Out[3]: [(1, 1, 1),
         (1, 3, 2),
         (2, 3, 1),
         (3, 3, 3),
         (1, 1, 1),
         (1, 3, 1),
         (2, 3, 2),
         (3, 3, 3),
         (1, 1, 1)]
```

Up to you how you get that back into the original `df`.  Please note two mistakes in your question: (1) the first `G_NUM` in the `df` is 15 not 5, and (2) the `PRI` sequence rank indices are wrong for rows 5-7 since they don't increment.

You should read on [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) techniques in `Pandas`.  The elements in the `zip` in my code above serve the following purpose:

- `pd.cumcount()` counts how many items have preceded the given element, and applying it on a `grouped` object projects this calculation onto each group.
- `grouped.transform(len)`  counts the number of elements in each group and yields that as a scalar value for each given observation.
- `grouped.transform(lambda x: np.argsort(~x.values)+1)` handles your specification for priority: `np.argsort` finds the rank of a given element within a list -- in other words, it gives the permutation under which the list would be sorted.  By applying the argsort to ~x.values, we sort in descending order.  (I don't know if the `kind` keyword is actually necessary; I'm insisting on mergesort so that the sort is stable and so whenever the `PRIM` values are equal the original order takes precedence; at the moment I don't recall if the `quicksort` used by `numpy` as its default is modified to be stable or not).

Comment: Thank you. You codes look great. Just a question. Will df.groupby('G_NUM') put those elements not adjacent to each other in the same group if they have the same number? For example, if there is another row, say G_Num 15, at the end, I want that row to be treated separately from the first row.

Comment: Will it be easier to extract columns "G_NUM" and "PRIM" into a list of tuples, work through the list to find the information, and then add back to the DF?  Just found a similar question, but for a list: "How to find duplicates in a python list that are adjacent to each other and list them with respect to their indices?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549493/how-to-identify-duplicates-adjacent-to-each-other-in-a-column/53549855#53549855